# Folder Won't Commit to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I drag-and-dropped a folder (ChessEngine) to a project after the original project was on GitHub. ChessEngine originally had its own remote repo, so I deleted the .git file from that ChessEngine folder.  I then deleted the .git folder from the overall folder (ChessArmyKnife) and ran git init on the larger ChessArmyKnife folder.  Still the ChessEngine folder isn't being seen by GitHub.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before committing use git add command and re commit and push again

Comment: I tried that.  I also ran git init again on the larger ChessArmyKnife folder.

Comment: Is the folder empty?

Comment: The folder is not empty.

Comment: I solved the issue by simply deleting my remote repo and creating a new one with the same name and then committing the local repo.

Answer (score 0):

That folder is empty.since that folder doesn’t contain anything it’s not committing to the repo!!!

Comment: It's not empty in my local repo.  That's what I'm trying to commit.

Comment: I solved the issue by simply deleting my remote repo and creating a new one with the same name and then committing the local repo.

Answer (score 0):

That folder isn't getting committed because its either empty or all the files inside it are being ignored.

If the folder is used for content you don't want to commit in your repo but you do want to include the directory you can create a place holder file in the directory, convention is to name the file `.gitkeep`

then in `.gitignore` explicitly add exclude `.gitkeep` from the ignored files.

File: ./ChessEngine/.gitignore

```
*
!.gitkeep
```

The `*` is ignoring all the files in the directory. While `!.gitkeep` is explicitly excluding this file from the exclusion rule .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

To commit the folder to repo create a .gitkeep file in it and the.n commit it. Git will treat it as an empty folder only, but will allow you to commit.

https://fileinfo.com/extension/gitkeep
GITKEEP File Extension - What is a .gitkeep file and how do I open it?

Comment: Thanks, but the folder is not empty in my local repo.

Comment: I solved the issue by simply deleting my remote repo and creating a new one with the same name and then committing the local repo.